# Definiteness of Real Numbers versus Complex Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, complex-numbers, lp-spaces, real-numbers

In [these measure theory notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch7.pdf), $L^p$ spaces are discussed. Right after the title of the section "7.1 $L^p$ spaces", it is stated that, "For definiteness, we consider real-valued functions. Analogous results apply to complex-valued functions."

I am a little confused by this statement. What does "definiteness" refer to with regards to real-valued functions? How does this property of real-valued functions versus complex-valued functions simplify things?

Comment: It's because you can recover results for $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued functions (and even separable Banach space valued functions) by applying the $\mathbb{R}$-valued function results component-wise. For example, the dominated convergence theorem generalizes this way instantly. Though, some common proofs of the DCT would work without change in this more general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that what this is about is that the author wishes not to confuse the discussion of the concepts of $L^p$ spaces by having to pay careful attention to the notational differences between complex valued functions and real valued functions, and some of the implications of those notational issues which get in the way of the central concepts of $L^p$ spaces. The author believes it is possible to explain the concepts of $L^p$ spaces in a simpler and more straightforward manner by avoiding those issues.

Comment: Implicit in this is the fact that it really doesn't make much difference if we choose R or C - there aren't any important theorems that are only true for R, and not for C.  So the author is saying "we'll pick one, and we pick R". The fun thing is that a lot of the proofs for C look *identical*, it's just that the absolute value bars have a different meaning.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for this information. As a quick follow up, in this case, do you think the usage of the word "definiteness" is more literal rather than having mathematical meaning?

Comment: It definitely (pun partially intended) does not have a mathematical meaning in this context.